# Http request timed out only in GPRS/EDGE environment in Android phone

Tags: android, http, httpclient

I am developing an Android app, it will connect to the internet to load some data back.

I tested it with WIFI and it works well. But when I switched to use EDGE/GPRS, it always timed out, I have set a big timeout parameter for httpclient, but it did not help.

It may caused by the server side that it did not return back a Content-Length header. But I can not change the server code.

Anyone have experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, the problem disappeared the next day, seems a mobile network problem.